# Subtract two columns from two different tables successively

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view

I have two tables, `twentyBuyer` and `twentySeller`, and in both of the tables, I have multiple columns but the one I want to pull out is `totalCost`. I have been trying to figure out a way to do so that I can subtract the `twentyBuyer.totalCost` from `twentySeller.totalCost` successively. The tables are like this below.

TABLE twentyBuyer

```
ID, Date,        Name,   TotalCost, Type
1,  "today",     "John", 46,        "ONE"
2,  "yesterday", "Doe",  506,       "ONE"
```

TABLE twentySeller

```
ID, Date,        Name,     TotalCost, TYPE
1,  "today",     "Franko", 273,       "ONE"
2,  "yesterday", "Bob",    207,       "ONE"
```

At first, I tried to pull the information using SELECT statements so I could just do the subtraction very easily doing `SELECT twentyBuyer.totalCost - twenty_seller.totalCost FROM twentyBuyer, twenty_seller;` to which I got

```
diff
299
-161
233
-227
```

I thought that this way was wrong so I Googled some and came across joins. When I started using `INNER JOIN`, I almost got the right results but there were two more results

CODE:

```
SELECT DISTINCT twenty_seller.totalCost, twentyBuyer.totalCost
FROM twenty_seller
LEFt OUTER JOIN twentyBuyer
ON 1=1;


totalCost | totalCost
207       | 506
273       | 506
207       | 46
273       | 46
```

I tried to add UNIQUE to it and nothing seemed to work. I then switched to views but was having similar problems. I deleted the views code but I was running into similar issues.

I want the results to be like

```
difference
-227
299
```

I apologize if this is a trivial question but I just cannot figure out how to do this and I think there is a simple solution that I cannot think of yet. Any help appreciated

Comment: What would be the desired result? And how these tables relate each other?

Comment: It was the difference in the last code block. I just want to be able to subtract the totalCost columns from both tables and get the difference

Comment: Check if this works for you: `SELECT twentyBuyer.totalCost - twenty_seller.totalCost FROM twentyBuyer inner join twenty_seller on twentyBuyer.ID=twenty_seller.ID`

Comment: Not really. I am getting the same results as I did in the third code block.

Comment: Are you sure? Check the answer posted by @Mureinik, but I'm pretty sure they are the same...

Comment: I just updated the code above. Since both ID's are not the same in both tables, I was comparing them with `twentyBuyer.type=twenty_seller.type`. Would that be the cause of this issue?

Comment: It could be. In my first comment I was asking you how both tables relate each other, and I thought it was with the ID. If not, you have to update one or the other, in a way that one row point to one row in the other table.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. Inner join on c is cross join where c. Left join on true is inner join on true is cross join. That pairs every left table row with every input table row. Presumably you want an inner join where names or something are equal & you want the names or somethings (& maybe more) returned with their differences. But you don't say or even give an example of what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the "AS" clause with some math thrown in.

You're also not giving it any columns to match, which means that ALL the rows from BOTH tables are just going to be returned as is.

You can fix this by giving it a specific column to match.

Like so:

```
SELECT 
  twenty_seller.totalCost AS 'cost1',
  twentyBuyer.totalCost AS 'cost2',
  twenty_seller.totalCost-twentyBuyer.totalCost AS 'Difference'
FROM twenty_seller
LEFT OUTER JOIN twentyBuyer ON twenty_seller.ID=twentyBuyer.ID;
```

Or, if you just want the difference:

```
SELECT 
  twenty_seller.totalCost-twentyBuyer.totalCost AS 'Difference'
FROM twenty_seller
LEFT OUTER JOIN twentyBuyer ON twenty_seller.ID=twentyBuyer.ID;
```

And if you want the total over all the rows:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(twenty_seller.totalCost)-SUM(twentyBuyer.totalCost) AS 'Difference'
FROM twenty_seller
LEFT OUTER JOIN twentyBuyer ON twenty_seller.ID=twentyBuyer.ID;
```

Comment: It almost works but I am getting four rows instead of one. It is similar to the fourth code block I had with the exception of your calculation column.

Comment: Updated! Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand why I am still getting four rows even there are supposed to only be two rows. And, I am also not comparing them based on `ID` because they are different. I am comparing them on `type` but I don't think that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The database doesn't attempt to match rows from the two tables - it performs a Cartesian product (i.e., matching every row from the first table with every row of the second table), and it's up to you to provide a condition telling the database how to join these rows.

In the first example, you don't have a condition, so you're getting 2*2 = 4 rows. This is called a cross-join.
In the second example, the condition of 1=1 always evaluates as true, so although it doesn't like it, it's also a cross-join, and produces the same results as the first query.

Assuming you meant to match the rows with the same IDs, you need to provide this logic as a condition:

```
SELECT td.id, ts.totalCost - tb.totalCost
FROM   twenty_seller ts
JOIN   twentyBuyer tb ON ts.id = tb.id;
```

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what `td.id` is and what `ts` is in `FROM twenty_seller ts`. Isn't ts twenty_seller? And, I changed up the code above because the id are different. As a result, I added a type column so it can match it with the word "ONE"

Comment: 'ts' is an allias for twenty_seller and tb is an allias for twentyBuyer. That way you can use tb.ID instead of twentyBuyer.ID

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, I am getting the same four results as I did in my third code block. Also, I am not comparing ID's because ID's are different. I am comparing them based on type: `JOIN   twenty_gp_data_buyer ON twenty_gp_data_seller.`type` = twenty_gp_data_buyer.`type`;`